# trigger on event onpopstate on load chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, browser

I am dealing with a problem that disable back button on browser, so my approach is using onpopstate event, When page load success, then I click back button on browser, it's not trigger on onpopstate event and still can navigate to previous page, if I do anything in page such as left, right click on page then click back button on browser, it trigger on onpopstate event and prevent back to previous page.
this issue just happened on chrome, safari works fine.
I tried to many implementation, but it's still not work on chrome browser.
Has anyone faced this problem yet?

```
ngOnInit(){
   history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
   window.onpopstate = ()=>{
       history.go(1);
   }
}
```

Comment: The Browser probably doesn't respect states on pages the user never interacts with. That way the Client can get out of being endlessly stuck on your page.

Comment: so you are saying it's problem of browser huh?. it's just happened on chrome, I tested on safari or firefox, and they work fine

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to use **PlatformLocation** which has onPopState listener.

```
import { PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common'

(...)

constructor(location: PlatformLocation) {

    location.onPopState(() => {

        console.log('pressed back!');

    });

}

(...)
```